# Non queried parameter - different behaviour SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report, which has a report parameter with the following properties:

- hidden
- allow blank value
- non queried
- default value ( non-queried ) : dd/MM/yyyy

Report is started using the `ReportExecution2005.asmx` webservice.

- On SQL Server 2005, the web service runs the report without problems.
- On SQL Server 2008 R2, the web service returns an error:

> This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report
>   parameter 'datumformaat'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must
>   provide a parameter value.

Can this be fixed somehow, to have the same behaviour as SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Think I found it, on SQL 2008, this parameter had a value NULL, which is of course incorrect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter contained a null value, which was causing the error